# Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. ASPNETWSRPProducer

Tags: asp.net, iis, liferay, wsrp

### ASPNET WSRP Producer

#### Enviroment

- Server Side
- APSNETWSRPProducer (producer)
- IIS
- ASPNET Site
- Producer Site

#### Client Side

- Liferay 5.2.3 Tomcat 6
- WSRP Proxy (consumer)

#### Description

I am trying to use Microsoft's ASPNET WSRP Producer.

I created a site and added a simple .aspx "Hello World!".
Created another site to host Producer.
Tried to get information from the consumer.

### Liferay Log

```
21:24:22,379 ERROR [jsp:165] org.apache.wsrp4j.exception.WSRPException: No message found.

Nested Throwable is:
Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
        at org.apache.wsrp4j.exception.WSRPXHelper.getException(WSRPXHelper.java:714)
        at org.apache.wsrp4j.exception.WSRPXHelper.throwX(WSRPXHelper.java:133)
        at org.apache.wsrp4j.exception.WSRPXHelper.handleWSRPFault(WSRPXHelper.java:660)
        at org.apache.wsrp4j.consumer.driver.ProducerImpl.getServiceDescription(ProducerImpl.java:464)
        at org.apache.wsrp4j.consumer.driver.ProducerImpl.getServiceDescription(ProducerImpl.java:391)
        at org.apache.wsrp4j.consumer.driver.ProducerImpl.getPortletDescription(ProducerImpl.java:490)
        at com.liferay.portlet.wsrp.WSRPProxyPortlet._getPortletDescription(WSRPProxyPortlet.java:681)
        at com.liferay.portlet.wsrp.WSRPProxyPortlet._getWindowSession(WSRPProxyPortlet.java:458)
        at com.liferay.portlet.wsrp.WSRPProxyPortlet._renderRemote(WSRPProxyPortlet.java:316)
        at com.liferay.portlet.wsrp.WSRPProxyPortlet.render(WSRPProxyPortlet.java:133)
        at com.sun.portal.portletcontainer.appengine.filter.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:126)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:69)
        at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:632)
        at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeRender(InvokerPortletImpl.java:700)
        at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.render(InvokerPortletImpl.java:419)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)
```

### Producer OutPutTrace.info

```
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/03/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <soap:Header>
      <wsa:Action>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/03/addressing/fault</wsa:Action>
      <wsa:MessageID>uuid:1d118ef4-8020-4fb0-a0de-4fcfaaa7e239</wsa:MessageID>
      <wsa:RelatesTo>uuid:a37a4393-badf-431e-8a22-ac010ba47596</wsa:RelatesTo>
      <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/03/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
      <wsse:Security>
        <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-179325ab-f6b6-4370-b883-eac6998e8cbe">
          <wsu:Created>2009-10-26T16:46:25Z</wsu:Created>
          <wsu:Expires>2009-10-26T16:51:25Z</wsu:Expires>
        </wsu:Timestamp>
      </wsse:Security>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
        <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
        <faultstring>Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. </faultstring>
        <detail />
      </soap:Fault>
    </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
</log>
```

Comment: I am also facing similar error. Requesting for help.